# All paragraphs are empty in an opened document in python-docx

Tags: python-docx

I do the following:

```
from docx import Document
document = Document('text.docx')
document.paragraphs[42].text
```

And it gives me  `''` whatever number I enter, and for loop to find and replace a word does not work. But if I save the document with `document.save('text2.docx')`, the document is not empty.
The document is relatively big and contains many different formatting, images, tables, styles.
My task is to find and replace a word in docx document with some correction of the following word, so I will be glad, if you suggest another tool

Comment: your code is correct ..if youre getting " " symbol it means the paragraph your'e accessing is empty

Comment: But I get it whatever paragraph I choose, but it is not true, the document is not empty

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: I want to know how to read the document. Other documents are read properly

Comment: you can read by using print statement print(document.paragraphs[42].text)

Comment: Can you provide a link to the document?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem and was able to read the document using docx2txt: https://pypi.org/project/docx2txt/